# Should I give my last four of SSN to the recruiter?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, job-security

A recruiter was very direct in asking me for the Last four of my SSN for a job at JPMC. I said no, use the last four of my phone number because I never heard of a job application where someone does this. Another recruiter from the same company with a JPMC offers another position with the company. He asked if I would be able to provide my full ssn and DOB at the time of offer, I said of course it makes sense at the time of the offer.

The lead recruiter then contacts me, does an "equation" for the salary and then states his best offer. What should I do? Everyone says go with your gut, and i would like a position at JPMC but wouldn't want an identity theft situation either. 
Is this normal?

Will i get my identity stolen with my legal name and ssn?

He said he will eventually need me to email or text my ssn to him when I have to accept the job offer.

Comment: Did the recruiter provide you with an actual contract yet? How far are you into the interviews?

Comment: Just a note, the last 4 digits of the SSN are the only "random" part to it. The first 3 are determined by your place of birth and next 2 are the "group number" which is just incremented over time as numbers get used, so is easy enough to guess with a date of birth. An educated guess on where you were born, along with DOB and the last 4 digits gives your full SSN away.

Comment: Still in the process of getting it submitted to the company. The only thing apparently stopping this is getting the ssn

Comment: Well I wasn't born in the US and they have no idea where I originally got my SSN unless they do a google search I guess

Comment: @rr99, that would make it trickier for a scammer, but still not impossible to guess your SSN with just the last 4 digits. Have you actually talked to anyone at the company, or just the recruiter?

Comment: What is JPMC and  DOB? Is this for a certain country, like US?

Comment: @guest, I take DOB to mean Date Of Birth and guessing JPMC is J.P. Morgan Chase, a large banking company.

Comment: @SethR: Thank you. Could the original poster put it into the question? Not.clear to me (not native speaker)

Comment: JPMC is JP Morgan & Chase
DOB is Date of Birth 

@SethR What?

Comment: @rr99 - Please edit your question and clarify it.

Answer (score 3):

> A recruiter was very direct in asking me for the Last four of my SSN
>   for a job at JPMC.

You were right not to provide the last four digits of your SSN.

I am 100% sure that this is a scam.

https://careers.jpmorgan.com/us/en/recruitment-scams-warning

> The lead recruiter then contacts me, does an "equation" for the salary
>   and then states his best offer.

That's not a job offer. It's really not. The hiring manager didn't even interview you yet.

You need to stop talking to these people. Stop answering their calls.

Contact the HR department of JP Morgan & Chase directly.

> Will i get my identity stolen with my legal name and ssn?

Yes, identity theft or some other scam.

Remember, this is not the only information they have on you.

They probably have your phone number, your email address, and they can probably get your mailing address through your resume or by googling your name.

Comment: Actually, my address is on my resume so I guess the DOB and SSN were the last steps! Wow!

I spoke with my college coordinator and she said that typically recruiters need SSN but theyre scared to ask in the beginning. Still in the dark about what do actually because the position is really good.

Comment: @rr99, Did you read the jpmorgan link I provided? What email address did they use? Keep in mind that email addresses can be spoofed. Which videoconference software did they use?  Your college coordinator is not seeing the bigger picture. If I had a student like you who told me something like this, I would get on the phone immediately and contact JPMorgan & Chase directly or someone I know at JPMC.

Comment: I looked at the link and I actually told them this in the call too that they shouldnt be asking me the ssn. Yet, they agreed to move forward with using just my phone number as a temporary place holder. Also, Im not sure how to contact someone at JPMC

Comment: @rr99, In what country/state are you located in? Did they email you anything? What email address did they use? What phone number did they use? Run it through google and http://whocalled.us If the number is real, it means they spoofed a real number. If it's not, you have your answer. Do some detective work. Again, I'm telling you those people are scammers. There is no doubt in my mind about it.

Comment: So I went through with the interview and the phone. numbers were legit. The Interview was super weird as the manager could not get Zoom to work so he just did it over a phone call

Comment: @rr99, So you have your answer right there. JPMC only uses HireVue. If JPMC tried using Zoom, Hangouts, Skype, or anything else, it's not JPMC. That's what they wrote on their web page: https://careers.jpmorgan.com/us/en/recruitment-scams-warning Also, that same web page already made it clear that if someone asks that information they asked of you, it's not them. So now, you don't have just one confirmation that they're scammers, you have two. And yes, "legit" doesn't mean anything. Legit numbers can be spoofed. And some numbers can be made to appear legit through fake listings.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you will have to provide your SSN and DOB when joining a company.  The only circumstances where you should provide this information is after you have accepted an offer.  Also, this is not information that you should be sending through email or a text message as neither are secure forms of communication.  Tell the recruiter that you will give them the information in person at the company office after you have accepted their offer.  Obviously they will need to see official identification to verify that you are who you claim to be.  Make sure to do your research and determine that:

- This is a real company
- You will be going to the company's official location

If they refuse, then I would consider it a huge red flag and would cease communication with these recruiters as they are likely trying to steal your identity.

Comment: Even if this is a fully remote position, the company needs to provide some secure form of communication for OP to provide this information.

Comment: There are secure ways to digitally sign documents.  You should never provide PII (Personally Identifiable Information) within an unencrypted email.  If somebody is asking for this information, before you have the job, it’s a scam to get your information.  Yes; That’s how comfortable and confident, what you describe is a scam.